# Tikz: Impulse response vs. pole location

Tags: tikz-pgf, control

I'm wondering how getting started to type this Impulse response vs. pole location map in Tikz.

[image: ImG]

it is very similar to the Poincaré-Diagram at:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/poincare/

someone can type an example to get started?

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example. The smaller graphs are defined as `pic` and are placed near the poles. The positioning of the graph with repect to pole can be adjusted with the `xshift` and `yshift` keys of `scope` while defining `scope`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{
pole/.style={blue},
grapha/.pic={
\begin{scope}[scale=0.3,xshift=-2cm, yshift=-4cm]
\draw[fill=gray!30] (-0.4,-0.4) rectangle ++(4,3);
\draw[->] (-0.4,0) -- ++(3.8,0)node[above]{$t$}; % axis
\draw[->] (0,-0.4) -- ++(0,2.8)node[right]{};
\draw[thick,domain=0:2.5]    plot (\x,{0.3*\x*\x});
\end{scope}
},
graphb/.pic={
\begin{scope}[scale=0.3,xshift=-2cm, yshift=3cm]
\draw[fill=gray!30] (-0.4,-1.5) rectangle ++(4,3);
\draw[->] (-0.4,0) -- ++(3.8,0)node[above]{$t$}; % axis
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- ++(0,2.8)node[right]{};
\draw[thick,domain=0:2.5]    plot (\x,{cos(8*\x r)});
\end{scope}
},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[->] (-5,0) -- ++(10,0)node[below]{$Re(\sigma)$}; % axis
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- ++(0,10)node[right]{$Im(\sigma)$};

% poles
\node[pole] (a) at (3,0){$\times$};
\node[pole] (b) at (0,3){$\times$};

%
\draw pic  at (a) {grapha};
\draw pic  at (b) {graphb};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a great place to start for the OP!. If I were to make one small suggestion is that the part `\draw[fill=gray!30] (-0.4,-1.5) rectangle ++(4,3);` repeats itself in every graph, and could fit nicely into its own style =) Similarly with `\draw[->] (-0.4,0) -- ++(3.8,0)node[above]{$t$}; % axis
\draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- ++(0,2.8)node[right]{};` as there only seem to be two variations to there the `x-axis` is placed =) Great answer again!

Comment: Nice!! Thank you very mich :) Tikz is Great

Answer (score 3):

This is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503595), where a similar problem was solved. You can add the function to the `pic`, e.g.

```
\path pic{graph={cos(1440*\t)*0.4*(1+0.1*\t)}};
```

i.e. you do not need to define a pic for each different graph. This will draw a plot of the function `cos(1440*\t)*0.4*(1+0.1*\t)` in the domain `0:0.9` (which I guessed from your screen shot). Obviously, `\t` is the variable of the function. By default, the mini axis will fit the plot and the additional point `(0,0)`. If you want to extend the axis, you need to add extra points, e.g.

```
\path pic[graph/extra points={(0,0) (0,1)}]{graph={0.5+0.1*\t}};
```

make the axis to extend further upwards. For your convenience I also add a `xmark` for the crosses. Here is some complete example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/graph/.style={code={
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=temp]
    \draw[thick]      plot[variable=\t,domain=0:0.9,samples=101,smooth] 
     ({\t-0.5},{#1});
     \edef\temp{\noexpand\path \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graph/extra points};}
     \temp
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[fill=gray!30] ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=-3mm]temp.south west)
    rectangle ([xshift=2mm,yshift=2mm]temp.north east);
    \draw[-stealth] ([yshift=-1mm]temp.south west) -- 
    ([yshift=1mm]temp.north west);
    \draw[-stealth] (-0.6,0) -- (0.5,0)node[below,scale=0.7]{$t$};
    \end{scope}
    }},/tikz/graph/extra points/.initial={(0,0)},
    xmark/.style={cross out,minimum size=1ex,node contents={},draw=cyan!70!blue}]
  \draw[-stealth] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[below]{$\re(\sigma)$};
  \draw[-stealth] (0,-2) -- (0,5) node[right] {$\im(j\omega)$};
  \path (0,3) node[xmark]  ++ (0,1) pic{graph={cos(1440*\t)*0.4*(1+0.1*\t)}}
  (1,2.8)  node[xmark]  ++ (1,0.5) pic{graph={cos(1440*\t)*0.4*(1+0.1*\t)}}
  (2.2,0) node[xmark] ++ (0,0.6) pic[graph/extra points={(0,0) (0,1)}]{graph={0.5+0.1*\t}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remarks:

1. It appears more natural to produce the inlay plots with `pgfplots`. However, it is nontrivial to make the axis very small. The predefined `tiny` axis is still 4cm wide. One *could* make it work (and place the axes with `at=(x,y)`), but this would be quite a hack.
2. Instead of a `pic` one could also use a `path picture`, as illustrated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503595). However, this is also not without drawbacks since adding a node inside a path picture is not really supported.

For these reasons I suggest to use a `pic`, even though the lack of anchors makes the placement less intuitive. (One *can* add the usual anchors to a `pic` by making it the only element of a Ti*k*Z matrix. I am wondering if anyone has thought of copying the relevant part from `tikz.code.tex` to "nodify" pics.)